# Node EJS include not parsing variable

Tags: node.js, include, ejs, bcrypt

I've been using the following code with success across my whole website, its just a variable that is passed to the EJS to load a header:

**Node**

```
res.render('main', {
    header: 'header1.ejs'
});
```

**EJS**

```
<%- include(header) %>
```

Today I switched from using "bcrypt" to using "bcrypt-nodejs" and now EJS gives me the following error every time I try and open a page.

Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\node\views( header).ejs'

It seems to have forgotten how to parse variables, but only when coupled with Include as other variables passed to EJS still work. Removing "bcrypt-nodejs" doesn't seem to have fixed the problem. Does anyone have any idea what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, has nothing to do with bcrypt. EJS has updateded, the proper syntax is now:

```
 <% include header %>
```